# Constructor reference - no warning when generics array is created

Tags: java, generics, java-8, language-lawyer

In Java, it's not possible to create an array of generic type directly:

```
Test<String>[] t1 = new Test<String>[10]; // Compile-time error
```

However, we can do this using raw type:

```
Test<String>[] t2 = new Test[10]; // Compile warning "unchecked"
```

In Java 8, it's also possible to use a constructor reference:

```
interface ArrayCreator<T> {
    T create(int n);
}

ArrayCreator<Test<String>[]> ac = Test[]::new; // No warning
Test<String>[] t3 = ac.create(10);
```

Why doesn't the compiler display the warning in the last case? It still uses raw type to create the array, right?

Comment: funny... writing `n -> new Test[n];` instead of `Test[]::new` (which should basically be the same) will again give you an unchecked compile warning

Comment: @Roland they both are de-sugered to the same exact byte code too. Indeed interesting

Comment: @Eugene: well, for the formal rules, it usually doesn’t matter to what the language constructs are desugared. But the compiler clearly should emit an *unchecked* warning here.

Comment: @Holger that was sort of my point - if they are de-sugared to the same thing, how come they both do not produce a warning?

Comment: @Eugene: well, `n -> new Test[n]` does produce warnings. But the desugared form isn’t sufficient to derive a rule. E.g., the implementation of `Function.identity()` is `t -> t`, which allows to get a singleton `Function` instance at runtime, whereas any other (non-lambda) code that would produce the same desugared (singleton) code, would produce an unchecked warning, due to different rules. In this case, the rules for `n -> new Test[n]` and `Test[]::new` also are different, still, I gathered the relevant parts for `ArrayType::new`. I also added an emphasis to the conclusion as you suggested.

Comment: This is indeed a bug. Good catch! We've filed [JDK-8175317](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175317) to track this.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the Eclipse version I tried, exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your question is justified. In short, the method reference does indeed use the raw type (or should use the raw type) and the reason, why the creation of generic arrays is forbidden, still applies when using method references, hence, being able to silently create a function creating a generic array clearly violates the intention of the language design.

The reason why the creation of generic array is forbidden, is that the array type inheritance, stemming from a pre-Generics era, is incompatible with the generic type system. I.e. you can write:

```
IntFunction<List<String>[]> af = List[]::new; // should generate warning
List<String>[] array = af.apply(10);
Object[] objArray = array;
objArray[0] = Arrays.asList(42);
List<String> list = array[0]; // heap pollution
```

At this place, it must be emphasized that contrary to some answers here, the compiler does *not* perform type inference on the expression `List[]::new` to deduce the generic element type `List<String>`. It’s easy to prove that generic array creation still is forbidden:

```
IntFunction<List<String>[]> af = List<String>[]::new; // does not compile
```

Since `List<String>[]::new` is illegal, it would be strange if `List[]::new` was accepted without a warning, by inferring it to be effectively the illegal `List<String>[]::new`.

[JLS §15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) clearly states:

> If a method reference expression has the form *ArrayType* `::` `new`, then *ArrayType* must denote a type that is reifiable (§4.7), or a compile-time error occurs.

This already implies that `List<String>[]::new` is illegal, because `List<String>` is not reifiable, whereas `List<?>[]::new` is legal, as `List<?>` is reifiable, and `List[]::new` is legal if we consider `List` to be a *raw type*, as the *raw type* `List` is reifiable.

Then §15.13.1 states:

> If the method reference expression has the form *ArrayType* `::` `new`, a single notional method is considered. The method has a single parameter of type `int`, returns the *ArrayType*, and has no `throws` clause. If *n = 1*, this is the only potentially applicable method; otherwise, there are no potentially applicable methods.

In other words, the behavior of the `List[]::new` expression above is the same as if you had written:

```
    IntFunction<List<String>[]> af = MyClass::create;
…
private static List[] create(int i) {
    return new List[i];
}
```

except that the method `create` is only notional. And indeed, with this explicit method declaration, there are only *raw type* warnings at the `create` method, but no *unchecked* warnings regarding the conversion of `List[]` to `List<String>[]` at the method reference. So it’s understandable, what happens in the compiler in the `List[]::new` case, where the method using raw types is only notional, i.e. doesn’t exist in source code.

**But the absence of *unchecked* warnings is a clear violation of [JLS §5.1.9, Unchecked Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)**:

> Let `G` name a generic type declaration with *n* type parameters.
>
> There is an *unchecked conversion* from the raw class or interface type (§4.8) `G` to any parameterized type of the form `G<T₁,...,Tₙ>`.
>
> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw array type `G[]ᵏ` to any array type of the form `G<T₁,...,Tₙ>[]ᵏ`. (The notation `[]ᵏ` indicates an array type of *k* dimensions.)
>
> Use of an unchecked conversion causes a compile-time *unchecked warning* unless all type arguments `T`ᵢ (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*) are unbounded wildcards (§4.5.1), or the unchecked warning is suppressed by the `SuppressWarnings` annotation (§9.6.4.5).

So, a conversion of `List[]` to `List<?>[]` is legal, as `List` is parameterized with an unbounded wildcard, but the conversion from `List[]` to `List<String>[]` must produce an *unchecked* warning, which is crucial here, as the use of `List[]::new` does not produce the *raw type* warning that appears with an explicit creation method. The absence of *raw type* warnings seems not to be a violation (as far as I understood [§4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)) and it wouldn’t be a problem, if `javac` created the required *unchecked* warning.

Comment: Pretty good analysis. I still think that type inference is the reason why there is no warning. But I agree that it should not be inferring a type.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems like this warning is always silently ignored when an unchecked conversion happens from a raw method return type to a parametrized target-interface type, as long as you use a method reference. +1

Comment: jdk-9, build 157 - same `non-warning` behavior

Comment: I also noticed, that for the line `Test<String>[] arr = new Test[0]` there also is no _raw type_ warning. It only emits a warning for the unchecked conversion. Which could be justification for the absence of a _raw type_ warning in `Test[]::new`. Another option is to assume that `Test[]::new` _does_ do type inference, but always infers the type `Test<?>[]`, which is reifiable by [§4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7), since all type parameters of `Test` are unbounded wildcards.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee: but `Test<?>[]` is not compatible with `Test<String>[]`, so inferring `Test<?>[]` and silently assigning it to `Test<String>[]` would be worse than assigning `Test[]` to `Test<String>[]`.

Comment: @Holger, I did some spec digging myself, which changed my opinion. In [15.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) it states: _"A compile-time unchecked warning occurs if unchecked conversion was necessary for the return type R', described above, to be compatible with the function type's return type, R, and this conversion would cause an unchecked warning in an assignment context."_ where `R'` is the notational return type, and `R` is the functional return type. This is indeed, a blatant violation of the spec.

Comment: Yep, this is a bug. We've filed [JDK-8175317](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175317). I think this wasn't caught before because array constructor referencess are more commonly used in Stream.toArray(), and `toArray(List[]::new)` does issue a warning. This goes through a different path involving the target typing logic. Curiously, this case of a simple assignment doesn't get checked.

Answer (score 10):

The best that I can come up with is that the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B.13) specifies that a method reference to the constructor of a generic type infers the generic parameters: 
"If a method or constructor is generic, the appropriate type arguments may either be inferred or provided explicitly." Later it gives `ArrayList::new` as an example and describes it as "inferred type arguments for generic class," thus establishing that `ArrayList::new` (and not `ArrayList<>::new`) is the syntax that infers arguments.

Given a class:

```
public static class Test<T> {
    public Test() {}
}
```

this gives a warning:

```
Test<String> = new Test(); // No <String>
```

but this doesn't:

```
Supplier<Test<String>> = Test::new; // No <String> but no warning
```

because `Test::new` implicitly infers the generic arguments.

So I assume that a method reference to an array constructor works the same way.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13

"If a method or constructor is generic, the appropriate type arguments may either be inferred or provided explicitly."

Later it gives ArrayList::new as an example and describes it as "inferred type arguments for generic class," thus establishing that "ArrayList::new" (and not "ArrayList<>::new") is the syntax that infers arguments.

Comment: But if the type argument is inferred, that would imply a call to `new Test<String>[]`, which is a compiler error, since there is no way to reify over `Test<String>`. And _if_ it still ends up calling `new Test[]` (which is my assumption), this type inference is not a good explanation to why there is no warning imho.

Comment: Sure, type inference is a good explanation. The underlying call to the constructor is a runtime issue, where the generics are erased anyway. The type inference happens at _compile_ time, and has nothing to do with the call to the constructor. At all. It just depends on whether the compiler has enough information to enforce the type assertions, and type inference says, "Yes, it does."

Comment: It's legal to declare an array with a generic type, and it even works the way you'd expect. If you have an Test<String>[] and try to add a Test<Object> to it, you'll get a compiler error. Similarly you can declare varargs methods with generic types. The only limitation with arrays is that for whatever reason the array construction syntax only works with raw types.

Comment: The problem with generic array types is that you can always write `Object[] oa=genericArray;`, followed by storing, i.e. the ` Test<Object>` into `oa` without getting any warning. Even at runtime, there will be no check. This problem hasn’t been solved with method references and the type inference is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger do I understand you correctly? what is described in the answer is only partially true. The referenced JLS-part is not the solution, but rather there must be another part which should describe the behaviour for arrays and generics? if so I would like to see an answer stating what you wrote in your comment ;-)

Comment: @Roland: I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42351657/2711488) (took some type to gather the bits)…

Answer (score 5):

> It still uses raw type to create the array, right?

Java generics are just a compile-time illusion, so the raw type will of course be used at runtime to create the array.

> Why doesn't the compiler display the warning in the last case?

Yes, the unchecked cast from `Test[]` to `Test<String>[]` is still happening; it's just happening behind the scenes in an anonymous context.

```
Test<String>[] t3 = ((IntFunction<Test<String>[]>) Test[]::new).apply(10);
```

Since the [anonymous method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) is doing the dirty work, the unchecked cast effectively disappears from the managed code.

Comment: This is similar to my initial answer, but I don't think that it actually answers the question. Even though the "dirty work" is hidden, the effect is still the same, and the question was why the compiler wouldn't emit a warning in that case. I think that the correct answer (which I provided below) is that "new Test[n]" references the raw type Test while the method reference Test[]::new infers the generic type arguments.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I am not an expert by any means but I think constructor type inference is not the key reason. After all we are talking about arrays here. Guess we will have to wait until an expert weighs in.